# How to get Sqlite with PHPBB to work with apache2

Tags: apache2, php, sqlite, phpbb

I was wondering if anyone knew the steps/modules I needed in order for PHPBB to work with sqlite?
I've got mysql working, but I want to intigrate it with another piece of software that uses only sqlite, joy.
I'm using apache2, with php 7.2, though I have 7.1, 7.0, 7.3 and 7.4 available.
Any help is appreciated.